# Persian path for read_excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, path, farsi

I want to read a file with pd.read_excel and also load_workbook and I have persian names in my path. I get the following error: FileNotFoundError: No such file

my code:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(r'X:\\Frosh\\دیتابیس فروش\\ ثبت اطلاعات فروش.xlsx', sheet_name='پيش فاکتور')
wb3=load_workbook(r'X:\\Frosh\\ ثبت اطلاعات پيش فاکتور\\ ایجاد پیش فاکتور\\ پیش فاکتورها \\ ثبت اطلاعات فروش.xlsx')
```

I also tried to use encoding='utf-8', but again I receive an error regarding an incorrect element in read_excel.
I would be grateful if you help me. I should mention that I am coding for the company in which I am working and it is located in Iran so it's better to have path names in Persian in order to be understood by others.

Answer (score 0):

```
wb = xlrd.open_workbook("دیتابیس فروش ثبت اطلاعات فروش.xlsx", encoding_override='utf-8')
df = pd.read_excel(wb)
```

Comment: again I receive the same error:
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(r'X:\\Frosh\\دیتابیس فروش\\ ثبت اطلاعات فروش.xlsx', encoding_override='utf-8')
df = pd.read_excel(wb)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'X:\\\\Frosh\\\\دیتابیس فروش\\\\ ثبت اطلاعات فروش.xlsx'